# Enter a name instead of user id

Tags: laravel-6.2

I have 2 tables.

first table name is user.

```
User_id, User_name
```

Second table name is Question

```
Question_id, Question, User_id
```

I want to see the user name when I call the Question table.

table connection code:

```
 public function user()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
 }
```

And resource code is:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {

        return[
            'Question' => $this->Question,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at->diffForHumans(),
            'user' => $this->user->name
        ];
    }
```

Question controller show function:

```
   public function show(Question $question)
   {
       return new QuestionResource($question);
   }
```

The error during operation in the following code:

```
{
    "message": "Class 'App\\Model\\User' not found",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\forumapp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Concerns\\HasRelationships.php",
    "line": 718,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\forumapp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Concerns\\HasRelationships.php",
            "line": 179,
            "function": "newRelatedInstance",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class User extends Model
 {


    protected $table = 'user';
 }
```

Create an Elquoent model class because you have used **'return $this->belongsTo(User::class);'** User class here to define elquoent relation.
Hope it will work for you.